# Complete n-Digit Factor

Tags: python, performance

I Was trying a problem but my time complexity is very high. Is there any way to reduce my time complexity. The Question Below with my code.

> A number is said to be a complete ‘n’ digit factor, if it is a factor
> of all ‘n’ digit numbers when concatenated (joined to right) to
> itself.
>
> For example, 7 is a complete 3-digit factor as it divides all three
> digit numbers from 100 to 999 when concatenated to itself (i.e.
> 100100, 101101,102102, ... ..., 998998, 999999).
>
> Given the value of n and m(Max Value to be checked), write a code to
> generate all numbers from 2 to m (both inclusive) that are complete
> n-digit factor and print ‘No complete factors’ otherwise. For example,
> if n is 3 and m is 15 then print 7, 11, 13

```
N = int(input()) #No Of Digits
M = int(input()) #Max Value to be Checked
#Im Assuming Max Value will be less than or equal to 9
Nu = '100000000'
NuN = '9'*N
NuM_1 = int(Nu[:N])
NuM_2 = int(NuN)
Lis = [int(str(i)*2) for i in range(NuM_1,NuM_2+1)]
Count = 0 
Res = []
for i in range(2,M+1):
    Count = 0
    for j in Lis:
        if(j%i==0):
            Count += 1
    if(Count==len(Lis)):
        Res.append(i)
if(len(Res)!=0):
    for i in Res:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Why don't you `break` out of the `for j in Lis:` loop the moment `if j%i == 0` is not true? You also don't need `Count`, you can use `j` (if you `break`).

Comment: You also don't have to check even numbers (10...0110...01 is odd). Also: If one number fails all multiples of that number also fail.

Comment: What is the time complexity for your code? What are the max. values for `m` and `n`?

Comment: You don't need to check all the numbers up to 999999... - in fact, just checking the first *two* numbers is sufficient.  From the example: if both 100100 and 101101 are divisible by 7, then *all* of the numbers are divisible by 7, because they're evenly spaced.

Comment: Yeah..I'll try That @Timus. Is there anyway i can generate that list in short time? When N = 6 it's taking almost 11 Sec to make that list.

Comment: @a_guest N will be in between 2 to 9 (Inclusive) and M can be less than 200(Max value till it should be checked)

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper That Worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attacking the problem from the functional definition, rather than analyzing the numerical properties of that definition.

Concatenating an `n`-digit number to itself is the same as multiplying by 10^n + 1.  For instance, doing this with 3-digit numbers is equivalent to multiplying each by 10^3 + 1, or 1001.

A number divides *all* such integers iff that number divides the multiplier.  Therefore, you can drop this massive iteration and check; simply factor 10^n + 1.

For instance, 1001 factors into 7 * 11 * 13; from there, you can generate the seven needed integers in the answer: 7, 11, 13, 77, 91, 143, 1001.

There are many available factoring programs; a simple search will find you that code.

Comment: Nice insight. Didn't think of that !

Comment: I did pick up a few good tricks when I took Number Theory in college.  :-)

Comment: In fact. is is easy to show that the above condition is if and only if.   There have to be at least two n-digit primes, p, and q, and a number can only divide both p||p and q||q if it divides their gcm, 10*n + 1.

Comment: @Prune That was vey good. Didn't Even think of that!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation, using a `break`, and a faster creation of `Lis` :

```
N = int(input("Enter N: ")) #No Of Digits
M = int(input("Enter M: ")) #Max Value to be Checked
#Im Assuming Max Value will be less than or equal to 9
Nu = '100000000'
NuN = '9'*N
NuM_1 = int(Nu[:N])
NuM_2 = int(NuN)
Lis = [i + (i * (10**N)) for i in range(NuM_1, NuM_2+1)]

Res = []
for i in range(2,M+1):
    for j in Lis:
        if j%i:
            break
    else:
        Res.append(i)

print(Res)
```